# Azure ML- Execute Python Script -Datatime.date not working

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I am getting the following error when I try to convert a datetime variable to date.

**My Code**

```
import datetime as dt 

df['TXN_DATE_2'] = df['TXN_DATE'].dt.date
```

**Error**

> raise NotImplementedError('Python Bridge conversion table not
>   implemented for type [{0}]'.format(value.getType()))
>   NotImplementedError: Python Bridge conversion table not implemented
>   for type [] Process returned with non-zero exit
>   code 1

Can anyone please tell me what is going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the code below to convert as you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df['TXN_DATE_2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TXN_DATE']).dt.date
```

Hope it helps.